# Kinect - Detect where the user is looking

Tags: orientation, kinect-v2

I would like to detect whether the user is watching the screen or not using Kinect.

I've noticed when displaying the body joints orientation (W, X, Y and Z values) that the head joint returns 0 for all orientations. Why is that? Should I use other joints to determine this information?

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the user is looking at the screen, you can infer from it by having to detect a skeleton that is at a certain range maybe?

as for the return value 0, it means that it is not being tracked.
source : [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.trackingstate.aspx)

but basically if you can detect a skeleton, there is a high chance the user is looking at you

Comment: You're right, but I'm trying to figure out a more trustful way to know if the user is for sure looking at the screen or not. It's weird because I can retrieve the position of the head as it is beeing tracked but not the orientation (returns 0).